How to redirect back to List page in CAP application explicitly
I am working on the SAP CAP based app. I have disabled default Delete button and i implemented a custom button instead of that and when i am trying to delete the object using my custom button the object gets deleted, but the redirection to the List page is not working automatically.
There was some requirement of doing some other steps before deleting the object so we had to change the default functionality of the delete button.
Can you please help here what are the different ways to redirect back to the List page.
